# DataGridView SelectionChanged Event Not Firing when grid is zero height

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` that I am adding rows to programmatically.

Normally, when I add the first row of data the `SelectionChanged` event fires

But my Grid is anchored to the top and bottom of the form and when I make the form smaller such that the height of the Grid is zero, the `SelectionChanged` event does not fire when adding the first row.

Is this by design? It doesn't seem logical to me.

```vb
    With DataGridView1
        .Rows.Clear()
        .Columns.Clear()
        .Columns.Add("Col1", "Col1")
        .Columns.Add("Col2", "Col2")
        'uncomment the following line and the SelectionChanged event does not fire
        '.Height = 0
        .Rows.Add("foo", "bar")
    End With
```

Comment: What is the relation between selection changed and adding a new row? You should handle OnRowAdded event if you want to know when a row is added

Comment: @HarisHasan - You are correct there is no relation really I was trying to track down a bug and noticed this strange behaviour in the process

Answer (score 1):

This events fire every time when an **unselected** row is **selected** either grid is invisible or its hight is zero

When a row is selected and you try to select it again at that time event not fired
If you need to fire every time this event than first unselect that row and than select the same row in the case this event occure 2 time 1st for unselect and 2nd for row selection

```
dataGridView2.Rows[index].Selected = false;
dataGridView2.Rows[index].Selected = true;
```